# jsdom not loading external resources

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdom

I can't seem to get jsdom to execute external scripts and I can't seem to find any concrete examples. I don't get any error when I call my testing function, but nothing happens.

This is my code:

```
    var window = jsdom.jsdom(body).createWindow();

    jsdom.jQueryify(window, './lib/jquery.js', function () {
      console.log(window.$("#a1").text());
      window.testing();
      console.log(window.$("#a2").text());
    });
```

This is the html its loading:

```
<html>
    <head>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="stuff.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    Hi there

    <div id="a1">
    </div>

    <div id="a2">
    </div>

 </body>
</html>
```

My testing function:

```
function testing() {
    var a2 = document.getElementById("a2");
    a2.innerHTML = 'Second div';
    console.log("executed");
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [jsdom docs](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom)

Try this before the rest of your code:

```
require('jsdom').defaultDocumentFeatures = {
  FetchExternalResources   : ['script'], 
  ProcessExternalResources : ['script'],
  MutationEvents           : '2.0',
  QuerySelector            : false
}

var window = jsdom.jsdom(body).createWindow();

jsdom.jQueryify(window, './lib/jquery.js', function () {
  console.log(window.$("#a1").text());
  window.testing();
  console.log(window.$("#a2").text());
});
```

/fyi #node.js IRC welcomes you: http://bit.ly/nodeIRC

Comment: This answer is wrong after the latest updates. MutationEvents needs to be "2.0" instead of false.

Comment: what is body here ?

Comment: `body` is the html for your page - definitely check out the latest docs for jsdom, probably a lot has changed